# Is it possible to load res( like image) in storyboard or nib files from cocoa touch framework?

Tags: xcode8, cocoa-touch

I want to use images from cocoa touch framework that I add to my workspace, in storyboard or nib files.

I search and I found answer and tutorials like [this](https://www.tapglue.com/blog/ios-frameworks-storyboards-swift/index.html) that say how to use res in code but I want use it in storyboard and nib files.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Comment: @BartoszBialeckiNo, I didn't :(

Comment: It's a pity. I think it's probably impossible with storyboard.

Comment: @BartoszBialecki Yeah, I think so

Answer (score -1):

I might not understand your question but accessing images in storyboard/xib files are quite simple.

**1)** Add the image to your "Assets.xcassets" - take note of the name. "cars"

[image]

**2)** Then in StoryBoard add an ImageView and in the inspector type the name of the image in the "Image" field

[image]